# Twitter and Instagram Embed WCAG

Tags: embed, wcag

Our site is trying to be as WCAG compliant as possible, but we are challenged when trying to embed Tweets and Instagrams.

The embed code looks like `<blockquote>....</blockquote>` but renders on the fly to `<iframe></iframe>`

Since we have no control over the rendered view, the iframe doesn't have a title for example.

Is there a way or an recommendation to put something in a surrounding `<div>` that can at least warn the screen reader or other tools that an iframe is happening on an external site.

I tried using `aria="section" label="External Website in Iframe"` for example, but I don't know if that gets used by the tools and if it's effective enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would add a title on all iframes on the fly, with Javascript - if I would have the correct title. Or make a plugin (wrapper) so that when author pastes the URL of a tweet she must also write the title and then make Javascript to add title attribute to the iframe.

Maybe worth trying?

Comment: the blockquote is converted by JS into the iFrame on the fly already.  I would need to loop until the iframe is visible even after load.  I would agree it is possible, just really really ugly.

Comment: Then can you just generate the iFrame title at the same time maybe? Would have to see the code :D

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it by grabbing the IFRAME HTML, adding the missing TITLE attribute, wrapping it in a DIV (weird clearfix issue) and publishing that instead. I have only tested this in regard to Instagram.